# parser for arithmetic expressions

Tags: java, parsing, math, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to implement a simple parser for solving arithmetic expressions,such as
 "(9+7)*(10-4)".Right now I am just testing my codes with some simple calculations like "9+7" etc. It allows the user to input an string but after i enter the expression and clicked enter, nothing happened(blank in the console). Here are my codes:

```
public class parser {
//check whether if a string is an integer 
public static boolean isInteger (String s){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expression ;
    System.out.println("Enter an arithmetic expression: ");
    expression  = input.nextLine();
    //for storing integers
    String [] store = new String[100];
    //stack for storing operators
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    //split the string
    String [] tokens = expression.split("");


    for (int i = 0; i <tokens.length; i ++){
        if (isInteger(tokens[i])== true){
            store[i] = tokens[i];

        }
        if (tokens[i] == "+"){
            while (!stack.isEmpty()){
                stack.push(tokens[i]);

            }
            for (int j= 0; j <store.length; j ++){
                int x = Integer.parseInt(store[j]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(store[j+1]);
                int z = x+y;
                System.out.println(z);
            }               
        }       
    }
}

}
```

The codes are incomplete so it looks a little messy. I was trying to follow the algorithms provided on this webpage http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html.

Comment: Have you walked through the parsing flow with a debugger?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/19988147/2970947

Comment: What are you expecting `String [] tokens = expression.split("");` to do for you?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem is

```
tokens[i] == "+"
```

In Java the '==' compares reference values. It works for primitive types like 'int' or 'double' but with object types like String or Integer things get more complicated.
A simple example:

```
"+" == "+" // always true
new String("+") == "+" // always false - this is what you are actually doing here
"+".equals(new String("+")) // always true
```

what you want is actually:

```
"+".equals(tokens[i]) // this will compare the actual value
```

One more thing on the algorithm you want to use. I think the notation you want to use is called [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). You need to convert your input first - there's an example on wikipedia.