# Create Java stacks

Tags: java, stack

```
public static int evaluate(Scanner input)
    {
        if (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            return input.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            String operator = input.next();
            int operand1 = evaluate(input);
            int operand2 = evaluate(input);
            return evaluate(operator, operand1, operand2);
        }
    }

    // pre : operator is one of *, /, %, + or -
    // post: returns the result of applying the given operator to
    //       the given operands
    public static int evaluate(String operator, int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        if (operator.equals("*"))
        {
            return operand1 * operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("/"))
        {
            return operand1 / operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("%"))
        {
            return operand1 % operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("+"))
        {
            return operand1 + operand2;
        }
        else if (operator.equals("-"))
        {
            return operand1 - operand2;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("illegal operator " + operator);
        }
    }
```

I want to take this code and convert it to 2 stacks (one stack for the operators and the other stack for the operands) for using prefix expressions in a user-input GUI with an actionlistener. How can I write the code to convert this code to 2 stacks? By the way, this is homework and I understand that you're not allowed to give me the answers outright, so if you can provide me easy-to-understand pseudo code, that will be much appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Cough](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19988147/2970947).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Cough, cough, cough, cough!

Comment: What specific problem are you having? This is a question and answer website, not a coding service site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo is here:

```
public static int evaluate(Scanner input)
    {
        if (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            int stack_top_value=input.nextInt();
            stack_for_operand.push(stack_top_value);
            return stack_top_value;
        }
        else
        {
            String operator = input.next();
            stack_for_operator.push(operator);

            int operand1 = evaluate(input);
            int operand2 = evaluate(input);
            return evaluate(operator, operand1, operand2);
        }
    }
```